# How to start tomcat in Linux Ubuntu from Java or Scala program

Tags: linux, tomcat, nginx

I need to start tomcat, nginx, kafka etc from scala or java program, I am able to check through java program that if they are running or not using `ps-ef| grep nameofservice` but if they are not running I want them to start itself from java or scala program, I tried this for tomcat

```
val pr = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin","-c","echo def123@| sudo -S startup.sh"))
```

but it's not working.

Comment: @halfer, I tried this `val pr = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh")` but its not working..

Comment: Odd, I thought I had commented here. Please clarify what "not working" means - it is not clear. Do you get any errors? Have you checked your return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Java you can achieve this like below if you are using Windows OS

```
String startupBat = "c:\Software\Tomcat.version\bin\startup.bat";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

For Linux You have to use sh script

```
try{
String startupSh = "/home/Software/Tomcat.version/bin/startup.sh";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startupSh );
}catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Another Solution is this

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start " + PATH_TO_TOMCAT + "//catalina.bat run ", null, new File(PATH_TO_TOMCAT));
```

Here you can check  [Java Code Examples for org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat)

Comment: its not woking, I am on linux

Comment: can u publish Another Solution for linux also

Comment: @simply, wanted to start tomcat, nginx etc but experimenting with tomcat only, so trying to start tomcat using scala or java program I tried `val pr = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh")`

Comment: Are you sure your tomcat run on port `8080` ? Also how you  should sure no excpeiton happeing when you run the command from java code ass try-catch

Comment: yes when I start it through terminal i check it on 8080

Comment: I dnt know about Scala use code i provided you and add `try/catch` block if some exception it will show you.

Comment: this is how I start it from terminal `sudo sh startup.sh`

Comment: @It also asks for password when I start it first time I open new terminal

Comment: yes `sudo` will ask password its linux command and you run command as a root

Comment: does matter java or scala only this line should work `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh")` also i will try try catch now

Comment: cmd keyword its not recognizing

Comment: Where is CMD? in your code which you added in comment section? Are you trying another code? So What ever code you tried it throw exception and you saying server not started

Comment: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: tried to run it from apache-tomcat-8.0.5 folder but still same error

Comment: lets discuss it here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89810/discussion-between-aamir-and-subodh

Comment: @ lets discuss it here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89810/discussion-between-aamir-and-subodh , if ur ok with it

Answer (score -1):

In Java you need to use a ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command, option1, option2);

// Optional redirect
// builder.redirectOutput(file);

Process p = builder.start();
```

More info:
[java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: can u elaborate what r option1,2

Comment: See the javadoc, you can also set the working directory (.../bin).

Comment: ur answer is not clear an u specify it with 1 example